# Confused about inverse grep

Tags: grep

So, when you use inverse in grep (`egrep -v`), this literally means the output is shown upside down (flipped over)?

I think I was  more confused when I saw the following examples

```
$ egrep -v '\ ' blah.sh
$ egrep -v '(\ )|^$' blah.sh
```

I'm confused about what '\ ' does, and what happens if you put -v. Also what is the difference between '\ ' and '(\ )' command if we are excluding |^$ command?

Answer (score 4):

As vonbrand said, `-v` means print lines that do not match the pattern. This is best explained by example. Say I have a file called `foo.txt` whose contents are:

```
aaa
bbb
aabb
```

So, lets `grep` for some strings in that file:

```
$ egrep 'a' foo.txt ## print lines that contain 'a'
aaa
aabb
$ egrep -v 'a' foo.txt  ## print lines that do not contain 'a'
bbb
```

---

Now, the specific regexes you have posted don't really make much sense by themselves. Where did you find them? Anyway, in many regular expression flavors, `\` [escapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the next character, '\ ' is a way of typing a space in many shells. This is not necessary when using GNU `grep`, but `'\ '` means look for spaces. For example:

```
$ cat foo.txt
aaa
bb cc
$ grep '\ ' foo.txt
bb cc
$ grep ' ' foo.txt # same as the previous one, at least for GNU grep
bb cc
$ grep -v '\ ' foo.txt # print lines that do not contain spaces
aaa
```

`|` means logical OR, `^` matches the start of a string and `$` matches the end.. So, `\ |^$` will match any line that contains at least one space, or an empty line:

```
$ cat foo.txt
aaa

bbb
cc dd
$ egrep '\ |^$' foo.txt # print lines that are either empty, or have spaces

dd ee
$ egrep -v '\ |^$' foo.txt # print lines that are neither empty, nor have spaces
aaa 
bbb
```

The parentheses, allow you to capture a pattern:

```
   Back References and Subexpressions
       The back-reference \n, where n is a single digit, matches  the
       substring   previously   matched   by  the  nth  parenthesized
       subexpression of the regular expression.
```

They are not doing anything useful in the regular expression you have posted. An example of their usage would be:

```
$ cat foo.txt
aaaa
aa bb

aabbccbb
$ egrep '(bb)..\1' foo.txt  
aabbccbb
```

The regular expression `(bb)..\1` means match the string `bb`, any two characters (`..`) and then the string `bb` again (`\1`).

Answer (score 1):

`grep pattern file(s)` shows the lines that *match* the `pattern`; `grep -v pattern file(s)` shows the lines that do *not match* the pattern. If you merge the outputs of both in the correct order, you get the `file(s)` back.

Comment: I think, also need to add `-E` or `egrep` .

Comment: @RahulPatil, the difference between `grep` and `egrep` (or `grep -E`) is the exact regular expression language handled, nothing else.

Comment: I knew it, if he just use as you mention in answer `grep pattern file`  eg. `grep -v '^#|^$' file` , then it will not work , he have to use `-E` (or egrep ) option to grep.

Comment: @RahulPatil vonbrand did not give any pattern, he just explained `grep`'s `-v` flag which has exactly the same effect whether you are using `grep -E` or not. `-E` enables extended regular expressions without which the regex _you_ give won't work, however, this works perfectly well `grep -v '^#\|^$'`.

Comment: @RahulPatil, it will work... just differently ;-)

Comment: @terdon it is working because you have added \ before pipe. and I knew that. DON NoT try to explain to me I know `man grep`  all is here :D , my intention was adding `-E` example in answer but you are explaining me WTF.